# Transition animation

Tags: css

I am very close to what I want to do but still some problems.

All I want is #sca to come from outside of the div and stays there all the time until page closes and I want this to happen with transition effect very smooth. I also want it to happen without an :focus, :hover, :active events, I want it to happen 2seconds after page opens.

if anybody could help me I would be appreciated.. this is so hard.

```
#sceneo {width:1200px;height:300px;border:1px solid red;margin:0 auto;}
#scenet {width:650px;height:300px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FAFAFA;margin:0 auto;}
#sca {float:left;position:relative;left:0;width:271px;height:180px;background: url(http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/7913/123hc.png) no-repeat;display:block;position:relative;right:300px; opacity:0.5; 
transition: all 2s;
-moz-transition: all 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: all 2s; /* Opera */
-webkit-transition-delay:2s;
}
#sca:hover {left:280px;}

<div id="sceneo">
<div id="sca"></div>
<div id="scenet">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're almost there! you'll need to create a KEYFRAME animation (as far as I know Opera does not have this yet, but webkit, mozilla, and new IE all support them)

There's a great write up at http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/webkit-keyframe-animation-syntax/ about how to use keyframes

here's also a quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wMVR/3/

from there it should be easy!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to deal with keyframes, you could use a CSS3 javascript library such as [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) that handles all the transitions and stuff for you. In my opinion, it is a lot easier than coding CSS3 by hand.

Here is an example that answers your question:

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hP6nN/)

**Javascript:**

```
$("#sca").transition({ left: '0px', opacity: 1, delay: 2000 }, 2000, 'in');
```